# Filtering a stream when given multiple conditions in parameters

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, predicate

I am trying to create a function that takes multiple predicate conditions and filters a stream according to these conditions. I cannot find anything but my retList just seems to consist of the input rather than a filtered version of the input.

Here are the instructions I was given:

> //TODO Make a Stream of Integer and set it equal to input  for each
>   predicate p on conditions, set this stream variable equals to the
>   result of applying filter(p) to the stream. after completing the for
>   each loop, collect the resulting stream  into a List as we have done
>   in previous problems,  return the resulting list

This is what I have currently:

```
public static List<Integer> matchAll(Stream<Integer> input,  Predicate<Integer>... conditions) { 
    Stream<Integer> stream = input;
    Stream.of(conditions).peek(p -> stream.filter(p));

    List<Integer> retList = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());

    return retList;
}
```

and this is how it is tested:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.of(5,7,9,11,13,14,21,28,35,42,49,56,63,70,71);
    Predicate<Integer> p0 = n -> n > 10;
    Predicate<Integer> p1 = n -> n % 2 != 0;
    Predicate<Integer> p2 = n -> isPrime(n);
    System.out.println(Matcher.matchAll(stream, p0, p1, p2));
    // should get [11, 13, 71] 
}
```

but what I actually get is [5,7,9,11,13,14,21,28,35,42,49,56,63,70,71], the input.

Comment: why not create composite predicate and pass it `p0.and(p1).and(p2)` and method `matchAll(Stream<Integer> input,  Predicate<Integer> conditions)`

Comment: @Deadpool indeed cleaner, made [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58829629/1746118) with a similar suggestion.

Comment: Why are so many people thinking of `peek` as the first attempt to solve a problem? It should be the *last* thing to be considered.

Comment: @Holger Indeed. At least after the mention in the JavaDoc explicitly in its [API Note](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek(java.util.function.Consumer)) => *This method exists mainly to support debugging, where you want to see the elements as they flow past a certain point in a pipeline...*. Quite possibly not many developers prefer reading the documentation while using an API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current implementation, you are not storing the "results" of the filtering anywhere. The `filter` method does not modify the original stream, which is immutable, but returns a new stream that only contains the matching values from the original stream.

One way to achieve this is to loop through your conditions, replacing the previous stream with a new one that includes the applied filtering:

```
public static List<Integer> matchAll(Stream<Integer> input,  Predicate<Integer>... conditions) { 
    Stream<Integer> stream = input;
    for (Predicate<Integer> condition : conditions) {
       stream = stream.filter(condition);
    }
    return stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Instead of risking to mutate the stream every time, it is easier to create a [composite predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58829629/1746118) to improve on the readability and just use `filter` once.

Comment: I the OP’s current code, there is no filtering at all. There is the statement `Stream.of(conditions).peek(p -> stream.filter(p));`, which doesn’t do anything as this stream has no terminal operation. If the `filter` calls happened, it invalidated the original stream in most implementations (Streams are not required to be immutable). In that regard, there is no filtering in your code either. You are only chaining filters to a stream, which become effective, once a terminal operation has been chained.

Comment: I expanded my answer to cover the whole method, to make things less ambiguous. In my original answer I only covered the part where OP hadn't completed the chaining of the filters until the terminal operation.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
public static List<Integer> matchAll(List<Integer> input, Predicate<Integer>... conditions) {
    Stream<Integer> streams = input.stream();
    for (Predicate<Integer> predicate : conditions) {
        streams = streams.filter(predicate);
    }
    return streams.collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63, 70, 71);
    Predicate<Integer> p0 = n -> n > 10;
    Predicate<Integer> p1 = n -> n % 2 != 0;
    Predicate<Integer> p2 = n -> isPrime(n);
    System.out.println(matchAll(list, p0, p1, p2)); // [11, 13, 71]
}
```

I see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51187234/10910098

Answer (score 3):

You could simply create a composite `Predicate` in your `matchAll` method and use it to filter the input stream as:

```
public static List<Integer> matchAll(Stream<Integer> input, Predicate<Integer>... conditions) {
    Predicate<Integer> compositePredicate =
        Arrays.stream(conditions).reduce(Predicate::and).orElse(p -> true); // or else filter in all
    return input.filter(compositePredicate).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

As [suggested by Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58829121/filtering-a-stream-when-given-multiple-conditions-in-parameters/58829629?noredirect=1#comment103941060_58829629), alternatively you can use:

```
return Arrays.stream(conditions)
             .reduce(Predicate::and)
             .map(input::filter) // Optional.map here
             .orElse(input)
             .collect(Collectors.toList()); // terminal operation
```

Comment: Or `return Arrays.stream(conditions).reduce(Predicate::and).map(input::filter) .orElse(input).collect(Collectors.toList());` Composition has the advantage that you can decide for `Predicate::and` or `Predicate::or`, whereas multiple `filter` calls on a `Stream` always imply `and` logic.

Answer (score 1):

In your matchAll function, you may consider to change following 2 lines to 1 line. Check if it works for multiple predicate filter of a data input stream.

**Change from**

```
Stream.of(conditions).peek(p -> stream.filter(p));

List<Integer> retList = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Change to**

```
List<Integer> retList = stream.filter(t -> Arrays.stream(conditions).allMatch(f -> f.test(t))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I assume it should give expected output. Hope it helps!

Comment: Its easier to create a [composite predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58829629/1746118) to improve on the readability and just use `filter` once.